# Apply HTML/CSS Custom Grid to Elementor Post Plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I've been Working on a real estate website on **Wordpress with Elementor Pro**.

Everything is fine and integrated, until my client asked me a **special Layout for the homepage Sold houses block display**.

Basically, i understand how to do it in HTML/CSS ( will link the code ) , but unfortunately i can't apply it to the Block.

Why ? **Because the block calls dynamically an Elementor Loop Template** which displays three posts ( the houses price and specs page are done with post + ACF Plugin to generate quick pages ) , so basically **i can't apply HTML/CSS directly on the block** ( because it applies on the block and not on the Loop content ) , and **i can't apply it neither on the Loop Template**.

I'm really new to Wordpress & Elementor even if i did some HTML/CSS , i don't really get how to target the elements and apply HTML/CSS on them, and even more how to **apply my layouts on dynamical content when it's called on another page**

Here is 2 pictures to help u understand my problem , **first on**e is what's actually on the site, and **second one** the wanted result. I'm joining the HTML/CSS code i did too.

Thanks for your reading

[image: How it actually looks lik]

[image: Wanted Result]

CSS Code :

```
.all_container {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  display : flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction : row;
  justify-content : space-around;
}

.main_container {
  width : 400px;
  min-height : 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
}
.big_div {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
   grid-row: 2 / span 1;
   z-index: 2;
  border-radius : 10px;
  background-color: yellow ;
    border : 1px solid black;
}
.small_div {
  background-color : lightblue;
  border : 1px solid black;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  grid-column: 2 / span 3;
  border-radius : 250px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.big_div_up {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
   grid-row: 1 / span 1;
   z-index: 2;
  border-radius : 10px;
  background-color: yellow ;
    border : 1px solid black;
}
.small_div_up {
  background-color : lightblue;
  border : 1px solid black;
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  border-radius : 10px;
   margin-top : 60px;
}

.big_div_down {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 5;
   grid-row: 3 / span 1;
   z-index: 2;
  border-radius : 10px;
  background-color: yellow ;
    border : 1px solid black;
}
.small_div_down{
  background-color : lightblue;
  border : 1px solid black;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  border-radius : 10px 10px 250px 10px;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<div class="all_container">
  <div class="main_container">
  <div class="big_div"></div>
  <div class="small_div"></div>
 </div>
   <div class="main_container">
  <div class="big_div_up"></div>
  <div class="small_div_up"></div>
 </div>
   <div class="main_container">
  <div class="big_div_down"></div>
  <div class="small_div_down"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand the loop content.  Do you use Woocommerce for the real estate property that gets called from the products?

Comment: No, i used Elementor Loop Template & ACF to call them from the Pösts list.

My problem is not the way i call them but the way i could design them like wanted.

Comment: I am testing the plugin.  Just to understand, how did your enter your property, are you using Post?

Comment: Good question!  I wasn't aware of this plugin before and it is quite elaborate, yet when it comes to details as in your case, the originator of the plugin may want you to go for pro.  I usually find a way around, if it is worth it, depending, I also go for the pro versions, But let's see if we can find some way around.  Any design you do on the 'block' would change the rest of the design.  I will see if it can be individualized.

Answer (score 0):

Elementor can be a little difficult to work around. I would recommend adding classes to your columns by selecting the column in Elementor, navigating to "advanced" in the third column, and adding the class name. Then write your styles in an external stylesheet, ideally a `style.css` associated with a Hello Elementor child theme. I would also recommend adding a class to the section so you can use it as a parent selector. You may have to adjust your code to include Elementor classes to target containers or columns (classes tend to be applied one div *inside* an Elementor block).

[image]